# uninstalled macports, and cannot use homebrew softwares anymore

Tags: bash, macos, installation, homebrew, macports

I'm trying to remove duplicate opencv versions on my mac. It seems that I have installed using both homebrew and mac port, so I decided to uninstall mac port completely, following [this guide](https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling)

But when I uninstalled mac-port and softwares installed with port, I couldn't use softwares installed by brew anymore

```
$ brew install pkg-config
$ pkg-config
```

`-bash: /opt/local/bin/pkg-config: No such file or directory`

I guess it's because the system still believes that pkg-config is in mac-port location. But how to fix it? I haven't find solutions with google.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by editing PATH setting in ~/.bash_profile (or bashrc).